# Wrong Scale with Report Printing (C# .Net) in EMF if application is running as RemoteApp

Tags: c#, reporting-services, remoteapp

I have an application that has uses the PrintDocument object for printing reports. Reports are rendered in EMF and everything is fine until you run the application as an RemoteApp.

As RemoteApp, the application cannot get the client monitor's DPI and will default to a 4:3 ratio. If the client's desktop resolution does not match this ratio, the report will be scaled incorrectly and thus, prints are also incorrect. For example, the fonts will overlap each other.

I know rending in PDF is fine, but it requires saving a temp. file first. However, I also require batch printing, so this may not be the best solution in terms of performance.

Does anyone know of anyway to get around this besides making sure the client desktop has the same 4:3 resolution ratio?

Comment: Setting PrintDpiX/PrintDpiY in DeviceInfo should help (check BOL for more options http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155373.aspx )

Comment: I have come across samples that set the Dpi, but I won't know what Dpi to set it to, since the client's monitor resolution is not fixed. Is there some way to obtain the client's monitor resolution while running as RemoteApp? I guess that's my other question..